# MongoDB Connection Docker Compose

Tags: mongodb, authentication, docker-compose

I have a docker compose environment where I define a mongoDB database to store sessions.

```
mongodb:
    image: 'bitnami/mongodb:latest'
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
    environment:
        MONGODB_USERNAME: test
        MONGODB_PASSWORD: test
        MONGODB_DATABASE: test
        MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
```

Logs, when I execute **docker-compose up**:

> mongodb_1     | mongodb INFO
>
> mongodb_1     | mongodb INFO   Installation parameters for mongodb:
>
> mongodb_1     | mongodb INFO     Root Password: ********** mongodb_1
>
> | mongodb INFO     Username: test mongodb_1
>   | mongodb INFO
>   Password: ********** mongodb_1
>   | mongodb INFO     Database: test
>
> mongodb_1     | mongodb INFO   (Passwords are not shown for security
>   reasons) mongodb_1     | mongodb INFO
>
> #

And when I try to connect to this database:

```
mongo --host mongodb -u test -p
```

The result is:

> connecting to: mongodb:27017/test Wed Sep 20 08:47:40.812 Error: 18 {
>   ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18, codeName:
>   "AuthenticationFailed" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228 exception: login
>   failed

If I execute a ping:

```
ping mongodb
```

> PING mongodb (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
>
> 64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.162 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.115 ms

So, I am not able to connect to this instance. I tried from different containers. Also from the same container but I always face the same error AuthenticationFailed.

Any idea what could be happening?